# Is there a way to console.log when a variable has a certain value?

Tags: javascript

I am a starter coder and cannot find the solution to this problem. I have tried the code

```
var X = "Angry";
if X = "Angry" console.log(X is Angry)
```

When I run this code I am informed of an error on the third line.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: You probably should learn the basic syntax of the language first!

Comment: This code is not constructed in a way that respects almost any of the well-defined syntax rules of the language. As Mamun says, you should learn these rules first or at least refer to them when trying to figure out syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `==` or `===` equality operator. Also, I would suggest  you should wrap your syntax for if blcok.

```js
var X = "Angry";
if (X === "Angry") console.log('X is ' + X)

// Best way
if (X === "Angry") {
    console.log('X is ' + X)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If x == "angry"

Double equal sign for condition of equality